# I can't get the value of a input value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, get

> This is my code.

```js
let firstname = document.querySelector("#name").value;
let add = document.querySelector("#add").value;

function adder() {
  alert(firstname);
}
```

```html
<input required type="text" name="" id="name">
<button onclick="adder()" id="add">add</button>
```

Comment: try to put `let firstname = document.querySelector("#name").value;
` inside `adder()`

Comment: zb22's suggestion points to the fact that you gather the input value while it is empty, and later alert the empty value without ever retrieving the "new" value of the input.

Answer (score 1):

this because your `firstname` value defined before you set value into text input

you can solve it by defining `firstname` value after calling `adder` function

```js
let add = document.querySelector("#add").value;

function adder() {
    let firstname = document.querySelector("#name").value;
    alert(firstname);
}
```

```html
<input required type="text" name="" id="name">
<button onclick="adder()" id="add">add</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for answered !

Answer (score 0):

Small tweak if you desire to have all variables together. You were assigning an empty string to `firstname` variable.

**HTML**

```
<input required type="text" name="" id="name" />
<button onclick="adder()" id="add">add</button>
```

**JS**

```
let firstname = document.querySelector('#name');
let add = document.querySelector('#add').value;

function adder() {
 alert(firstname.value);
 firstname.value = '';
}
```

Also reset the `firstName` value back to an empty string after clicking the button